# C# getting datagridview date in a datetimepicker

Tags: c#

i want to get date from datagridview and then show on datetimepicker. Date format shown on datagridview is in the format (i.e 23 June 2018) while the properties of datetimepicker are customformat=dd-MM-yyyy , format=custom.

I have the following code but it does not work. the if condition does not gets true. please help

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
     DateTime curDate;

     if (DateTime.TryParse(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString(), out curDate))
      {
          txtInvoiceDate.Value = curDate;
          MessageBox.Show(curDate.ToString());
      }
}
```

Comment: The DGV supports the NET DateTime type.  You ought not have to parse it to begin with

Comment: How do you expect `TryParse` to be successful with a custom string and no culture info?

Comment: DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString(), "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                txtInvoiceDate.Value = dt;

Comment: Exception throws: String was not recognize a valid DateTime

Answer (score 0):

You have the incorrect date format.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#the-mmmm-custom-format-specifier

As stated in your example, `23 June 2018` would be the format `dd MMMM yyyy`.

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string myDate = "23 June 2018";
        var newDate = DateTime.ParseExact(myDate, "dd MMMM yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        Console.WriteLine(newDate.ToString());
    }
}
```

Output

`6/23/2018 12:00:00 AM`

https://dotnetfiddle.net/pxmHOe